# MySQL update 1 row of table, previous table is being updated

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

```
$sql="UPDATE paper 
set 
$field='$data' 
where paper_id 
AND user_id='" . $_SESSION['edit2'] . "'";
```

I faced an issue that when I update title(column in paper table) for paper_id 2; user_id 1 the previous paper_id 1; user_id 1 also being updated.

Anyone can give me idea?

Comment: you are missing something here `where paper_id `

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql="UPDATE paper 
set 
$field='$data' 
where paper_id =".$_REQUEST['paperid']."   /* something that comes from your Request*/
AND user_id='" . $_SESSION['
edit2'] . "'";
```

Comment: Using `$_REQUEST` values directly are a bad practice, first need to sanitize them to avoid sql injection

Comment: I faced this issue Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_REQUEST' (T_VARIABLE), how im going to edit it?

Comment: @Eduardo Verdugo Cáceres : Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @user2659832 :  this is something that you will get from your request. or you can Manually set this based on your some values like used_id which you set from SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="UPDATE paper 
SET 
$field='$data' 
WHERE paper_id = '$something'
AND user_id='" . $_SESSION['edit2'] . "'";
```

Change `$something` for whatever you want

Comment: In addpaper:mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(username, password)VALUES('$username', '$password')", $con);
 $_SESSION['edit2'] = mysql_insert_id($con); In update:why it cant automatically update paper_id with user_id together without affect previous table? $somethings I dont know what to put actually, because I need it follow $_SESSION['edit2']. If i put that, database appear problem too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$paper_id = isset($_POST['paper_id']) ? $_POST['paper_id'] : '';

if ($paper_id)
{
 $sql="UPDATE paper 
 SET
 $field='$data' 
 WHERE paper_id = '$paper_id' 
 AND user_id='" . $_SESSION['edit2'] . "'";
}
```

**Notes:** paper_id should be passed from your form.

Answer (score 0):

$sql="UPDATE paper set $field='$data' where paper_id='" . $_SESSION['addpaper'] . "' AND user_id='" . $_SESSION['login'] . "'"

This is working now.

Thank you so much. 
Devs,
Eduardo Verdugo Cácere,
Ilesh Patel